# CSS border corner curve backward

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How can I make the below image using only html and css

[image]

Comment: can u use html5 canvas ?

Comment: Downvoters never tried to find solution, and thought it can't be done!

Comment: No proof of effort which is one of SO's key rules (not saying no effort but just none shown). I haven't voted yet but inclined to either down vote or close vote. And I don't think this can't be done, thats never a good reason for down-voting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using `:after` :pseudo-element with a single `div`.

```css
body {
  background: #88FF55;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #01CC00;
}
div:after {
  content: 'i';
  color: #01CC00;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 44px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

You could use `radial-gradient` for transparent cut.

```css
body {
  background: #88FF55;
}
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 188px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #01CC00;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, transparent 20px, #01CC00 22px);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, transparent 20px, #01CC00 22px);
  background: radial-gradient(100% 100%, circle, transparent 20px, #01CC00 22px);
}
```

```html
<div>i</div>
```

---

Or you could use `svg`'s `clipPath`.

```css
body {
  background: #88FF55;
}
div {
  height: 100px;
  background: #01CC00;
}
```

```html
<svg width="150" height="100" viewBox="0 0 150 100">
  <clipPath id="shape">
    <path d="M2,2 L146,2 L146,76 A20,20 1,0 0 126,98 L2,98z" />
  </clipPath>
  <foreignObject clip-path="url(#shape)" width="150" height="100">
    <div></div>
  </foreignObject>
  <text x="140" y="97" font-weight="bold" font-size="16" fill="#01CC00">i</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: definitely  one/the best solution, as it only has to initialise a single DOM element

Comment: I'd prefer to use a ufll circle, and then add an overflow hidden [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/xpwtwyp8/)

Comment: @jbutler483 - This approach has two advantages: 1) The text could be easily aligned to its right by adding `text-align: right`. 2) The :pseudo-element could be easily aligned to the bottom right by simply adding `bottom: 0` and `right: 0`.

Answer (score 3):

With absolute position and border radius:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
}
.info {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -7px;
  right: -7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="info">i</div>
</div>
```

Comment: there really is no need for multiple elements here. Using ::before and /or ::after pseudo effects is more than enough.

Answer (score 3):

Apply `overflow: hidden` and `position: relative` on the parent the use `position: absolute` on the pseudo element with `border-radius: 50%`

```css
:root{background: #333}
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden
}
.wrapper:before {
  content:'i';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  bottom: -4px;
  right: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Why isn't this answer upvoted more? probably the best so far!

Answer (score 2):

This solution has the advantage of not using magic values, just some simple positioning. The "i" is in it's own container so it can easily be styled or replaced by an image without fiddling with margins.

The circle is achieved by having the top left border radius equal to the container's width and height.

```css
.square {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.circle {
  background-color: white;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.icon {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class="circle">
    <span class="icon">i</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8b0kohv/)

Comment: Three elements for such a simple task = overkill!

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion. Fact is, it makes the styling very simple and flexible.

Answer (score 1):

add overflow hidden to box and your inner content position absolute + bottom right

```
<div class="box">
            <span>i</span>
</div>

.box {
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.box span {
    background-color: white;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the shape of the box, with the inverted border-radius in the bottom-right corner, do the following:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div:before {
    content:' ';    // fills div
    position:absolute;
    width:80px;   // width, height, top, left
    height:80px;  // are attributes of inverted
    top:70px;     // border-radius
    left:250px;
    border-radius:100%;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 1000px green; // box shadow creates the illusion
}                                  // of inverted border-radius
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L71euu59/

By playing with the **height, width, top, left** attributes of div:before, you can resize the border-radius and reposition it to whichever corner of the div you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

here another solution :)

```css
#logo {
  width:110px;
  height:72px;
  background-color:#1bc706 ;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#logo:after{
  content:"i";
  font-family:courier;
  font-weight:bolder;
  text-indent:-13px;
  line-height:10px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-15px;
  right:-15px;
  color:#1bc706 ;
  background-color:#fff;
  width:10px;
  height:25px;
  padding-left:25px;
  border-radius:100px;
  padding-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take one DIV and inside it create another DIV align inside's DIV position to most Bottom Right and make its left and upper border as you would like. Change its background color and you will get your image.